# How to create a group project in Xcode similar to using subversion?

Tags: xcode, project

We currently have a project requires 2 people participating. How can we create a project that allow it which acts as subversions ? or does sub-versions work with Xcode ?

Answer (score 1):

Subversion works with Xcode. And if you don't need IDE integration, you can use any source control system you want, since Xcode projects are just files that can be checked in like anything else. I've worked on Xcode-based projects out of cvs, svn, hg, git, and p4, and they all work just fine.